# How to check usage of Azure PVEP?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to check the usage of my Azure Private End Point (PVEP) but it really does not provide any useful information. I am interested in knowing the amount of data (in kb, mb, gb) but when I navigate over to PVEP blade, the information that it provides is not accurate. Does anyone know how to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

To check Azure private endpoint usage, you can make use of Azure monitoring metrics and insights like below:

In Azure private endpoint under monitoring -> Metrics -> add filter with time and aggregation:

[image]

You can use insight to determine whether the provided information displayed in the private endpoint blade is accurate.

***In Azure private endpoint -> Monitoring -> insights -> click show metrics pane -> Edit -> Add metric like below:***

[image]

Filter the time range and add metric:

[image]

Now both the values are same, private endpoint information is appropriate.

[image]

To know the amount of data (kb, mb, gb) you make use of PowerShell command:

```
$bytes = <YourPVEPbyte>
$kilobytes = $bytes / 1KB
$megabytes = $bytes / 1MB
$gigabytes = $bytes / 1GB

Write-Host "Bytes: $bytes"
Write-Host "Kilobytes: $kilobytes"
Write-Host "Megabytes: $megabytes"
Write-Host "Gigabytes: $gigabytes"
```

[image]

When I run in Rest API, I got same result as below:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01
```

[image]

***Reference***:

[Metrics - List - REST API (Azure Monitor) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list?tabs=HTTP)